driver installed but not available
I don't understand the problem here. The rtl8821cu is installed but I cannot modprobe it into place. Is there a problem with the install process or am I missing a step.
> pacman -Q | grep rtl
rtl8188gu-dkms-git r12.9dec829-1
rtl8812au-dkms-git 5.13.6.r189.gd4638de-1
rtl8821cu-dkms-git 5.12.0.1853eacc28-1
rtl8xxxu-dkms-git r54.fbb6d1a-1

[stephen@carb:~]
:> modprobe rtl8821cu
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8821cu not found in directory /lib/modules/6.9.7-arch1-1

After eyoung100 comment
`Packages (1) rtl8821cu-dkms-git-5.12.0.1853eacc28-1
`
`Total Installed Size:  36.99 MiB
`Net Upgrade Size:       0.00 MiB
`

...
==> Leaving fakeroot environment.
==> Finished making: rtl8821cu-dkms-git 5.12.0.1853eacc28-1 (Mon Jul  8 12:33:34 2024)
==> Installing package rtl8821cu-dkms-git with pacman -U...

...
-> Running build hook: [filesystems]
-> Running build hook: [fsck]
==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: 'cfg80211'
==> Generating module dependencies
==> Creating zstd-compressed initcpio image: '/boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img'
-> Early uncompressed CPIO image generation successful
==> Initcpio image generation successful


[stephen@carb:~/external/rtl8821cu-dkms-git]
:> uname -r
6.9.7-arch1-1

[stephen@carb:~/external/rtl8821cu-dkms-git]
:> dkms status
rtl8188gu/r12.9dec829, 6.6.36-1-lts, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/5.13.6.r189.gd4638de, 6.6.36-1-lts, x86_64: installed
rtl8821cu/5.12.0.1853eacc28, 6.6.36-1-lts, x86_64: installed
rtl8821cu/5.12.0.1853eacc28, 6.9.7-arch1-1, x86_64: installed
rtl8xxxu/r54.fbb6d1a, 6.6.36-1-lts, x86_64: installed
rtl8xxxu/r54.fbb6d1a, 6.9.7-arch1-1, x86_64: installed


try this package from the AUR, which I think you have, but the versions are different.  Post the output of: uname -r and dkms status.

@eyoung100 posted

You don't use modprobe with dkms "Dynamic Kernel Mode Switch"es are turned "on" and/or "off".  See Section 7.2.4 and lines 157 to 174 in the config file

@eyoung100 that's not what DKMS means.

@Hobbs Thanks! Better  to be Correct wit System, than Switch

Working now. Device had been renamed as wlan1.

Although the package is named rtl8821cu, the module name is simply 8821cu.
